# Finite-difference produces a derivative off by one order

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, differential-equations

I have a nonlinear 2nd order boundary value differential equation where I used finite-difference method (central finite-difference) to solve it.

$$z''(x)-\frac{\frac{1}{100} z(x)^4 \left(2 z'(x)^2+12\right)-600 \left(z'(x)^2+1\right)-\frac{3 z(x)^8}{500000}}{20 z(x) \left(10-\frac{z(x)^4}{1000}\right)}=0$$

Boundary conditions are,

$$z(0) = 93/10, \quad z(1) = 10^{-3}, \qquad x \in [0,1]$$

My interest is calculating both $z(x)$ and $z'(x)$, I have used $n+1$ points and `x[0]` as starting value for this calculation. In the end, after obtaining the data points for $z(x)$ I used interpolation to construct the function `zfunc` to represent $z(x)$. Taking the derivative of `zfunc` gives `zfunc'`.

I know that the derivative of $z(x)$ at one of the boundary is $z'(0) \approx -15.53574063$, but as you see `zfunc'[0] = -1.50198076`. I don't mind if the decimals are a little off but you can see that they are off by an order $O(10^1)$! This is unacceptable, is there something wrong with the finite-difference method that I wrote? I'm guessing it might have something to do with my starting values. I chose those starting values because I already have a rough idea of the curve and my choice is close to that curve.

The plot of `zfunc[x]` is shown below.
[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
f = 1 - (z[x]/zh)^(d + 1);
L = Sqrt[1 + (z'[x]^2/f)]/z[x]^d;(*Lagrangian*)
eulageq = EulerEquations[L, z[x], x];(*Euler-Lagrange equation*)
s = Solve[eulageq, z''[x]][[1]] // Simplify;(*2nd order EOM*)
eq0 = z''[x] - s[[1, 2]] /. {d -> 3, zh -> 10};

a = 0;
b = 1;
n = 250;
h = (b - a)/(n + 1);
alpha = 93/10;
beta = 10^-3;
Z = Array[z, {n + 2}];
z[1] = alpha;
z[n + 2] = beta; 
rul = Table[{z''[x] -> ((z[i + 1] - 2 z[i] + z[i - 1])/h^2), z'[x] -> ((z[i + 1] - z[i - 1])/(2 h)), z[x] -> z[i]}, {i, 2, n + 1}];
eqs = Table[eq0 /. rul[[i]], {i, Length[rul]}];
DFx = ResourceFunction["JacobianMatrix"][eqs, Table[z[i], {i, 2, n + 1}]];
x[0] = Table[(1 - i) alpha, {i, 1/100, 90/100, (90/100 - 1/100)/(n)}];

sol = FindRoot[eqs, Table[{z[i], x[0][[i]]}, {i, 2, n + 1}], Jacobian -> DFx, MaxIterations -> 1000, WorkingPrecision -> 30];

xx = Range[a, b, h];
lst = Table[{xx[[i]], z[i] /. sol}, {i, n + 2}];
zfunc = Interpolation[lst, InterpolationOrder -> 3]

zfunc'[0]
-1.5019807629446601256947800
```

I used Mathematica for the code.